# Spring integration outbound-channel-adapter and database persistence

Tags: spring-integration

I am working on an application which publishes a message to a queue using an outbound-channel-adapter. There is a new requirement that an unique id generated during the message processing should be persisted to database after a successful publish on the queue, without waiting for any reply.

Could someone please advise what should be the best approach for this.

This is what I have in my existing application.

```
<int:gateway id="writerGateway" service-interface="CustomService" default-request-channel="writerChannel">
</int:gateway>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="writerChannel" jms-template="jmsTemplate" destination-name="${queueName}" extract-payload="true"/>

<int:channel id="writerChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="writerLogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="writerLogger" logger-name="writerLogger" level="INFO" expression="'Sending ' + payload?.size() + ' events'"/>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
AK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `writerChannel` a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` and subscribe a second flow (`order="2"`) to it, e.g. `transformer -> jdbc-outbound-channel-adapter`. Set `order="1"` on the jms adapter and the second flow will be called if the jms send succeeds.

Alternatively, use a `<recipient-list-router/>`.

Comment: As suggested I changed writerChannel to publish-subscribe-channel and then used <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="writerChannel" order="1"> followed by <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="writerChannel" ref="jdbcDao" method="save" order="2">. This seems to be working.

Comment: I am facing a problem here because the original payload is transformed to XML. I can use claim-check-in to store original copy but I am lost as to how to connect the jms-outbound-channel-adapter and jdbc-outbound-channel-adapter as they have different channels for their input message.

Comment: Please don't piggy-back on already-answered questions; it's better to start a new one. You can use a header-enricher (`<header name="saveIt" expression="payload" />` to save a copy of the payload in a header. Later on you can either access the header directly or use a transformer to restore the payloasd.